# X-248 cape catastrophe

Tags: nasa, propulsion, qualification-testing

I was responsible for changing the ignition system on the fatal x-248.  It was a result of poor igniter design and especially dangerous procedures by Cape personnel.  I am looking for some facility of spin test facility photos if any.  Does anyone have possession of photos? Writing my memoirs

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40108/6944

Comment: Dear Mr. Pedolsky, the purpose of this website is to gather knowledge in a question and answer format. If you would like it answered, please find a better title and remove aspects that are irrelevant, so it is clearer what you are asking. If you would like to share other knowledge, please open a separate question. You are welcome to answer your own question then.